# javascript (frontend) <--> node.js (backend) | Simulate websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am hosting a little website using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I've got a node.js application too running on port 3000 and http calls from frontend (client browser) are reverse-proxied to node.js app running on localhost:3000. Everything works perfect.

The problem comes when i try to use socket.io.

I am encountering problems trying to reverse-proxy socket.io communitactions.

It seems that WebSocket support is not available in IIS 7.5.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

So without being able to use socket.io, i need to simulate it's functionality using javascript on the frontend and javascript too (node.js) on the backend.

I just need to:

1. Stablish comunication between frontend-backend.
2. Client will be waiting for 10 minutes for a message-event that will be sent from server.

   a) If the message is received then alert "ok".

   b) If the message is not received in 10 minutes then alert "time is up".

Regards,

Comment: Not clear what you're asking - do you mean that you need to implement a solution using your current architexture or you wish to simulate the behaviour for the urposes of testing?

Comment: i need to implement a solution using my current architecture.

Comment: Then put a COMET proxy in front of the socket.io server.

Comment: @symcbean, thanks for your answer. How exactly is this achieved?